# Scala: simplify case with comparison

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, code-cleanup

Let's say, I have the following code snippet:

```
val num = Future.successful(10)

num map {
  case n if n > 0 => // do something
  case _             // do something
}
```

My question is: can I simplify `case n if n > 0` somehow?

I expected that I can write something like:

```
case _ > 0 => // do something
```

or with explicitly specified type (although we know that `Future` has inferred type `[Int]`):

```
case _: Int > 0 => // do something
```

Can this code be simplified somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simplify `case n if n > 0 => ...`.

Every case clause in a pattern match needs to have a *pattern* and (optionally) a *guard*.

The syntax you are referring to (`_ > 0`) is only valid in lambdas, but there's no similar special syntax for case clauses.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to introduce such one in newer Scala versions?

Comment: I don't think this is even a proposal for now, but I don't speak for the scalac team. As a personal opinion, I would like to see special syntax removed from Scala rather than added.

Comment: Thank you, Gabriele. All that I wanted is to make sure that there is no way to simplify it.

Comment: Not sure if there will be any major changes in scala in this area, but have a look at dotty, next generation of scala compiler: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @Pavel keeping an eye on dotty is a good idea in general, but I don't think any syntax changes are in scope for this, not even in dotty

Comment: @Pavel awesome! Haven't heard about it until now (:

Comment: just dig around scala center -> https://scala.epfl.ch/, this is a good place to stay update whats going on

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simplify the guard, you can filter the `Future` a priori:

```
val num = Future.successful(10).filter(_ > 0).map { nat =>
}
```

Otherwise, you can keep the guard and use [`Future.collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#collect[S](pf:PartialFunction[T,S])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[S]):

```
val num = Future.successful(10).collect {
    case n if n > 0 => // do something
}
```

One important thing to note is that if the partial function is not defined for the value which returned (i.e for your case -1) then the resulting future will be a `Failure` containing a `NoSuchElementException`.

Other than these options, you'll need the guard. I don't see any syntactically shorter way to express it.

Comment: First variant is applicable if I need to do something in case of applicable Future result, but not if I need to return some mapped Future from function. Am I right?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov If I understand you correctly, yes. Since both these variants will not return the original future.